Efficiently fade all characters
I am creating an animation that fades the current frame before rendering the next frame on top of it. My current fade algorithm is very CPU intensive.
Is there a more efficient way to do the following:

Change every character on the screen to be slightly darker

My current algorithm is effectively:

Iterate every character

Create a new character with darker color
If new character would have no color, change to default character
Set the new character in the terminal



val fadeGraphics = terminal.newTextGraphics()
fadeGraphics.setForegroundColor(TextColor.RGB(0, 255, 0))
var frameCounter: Int = 0

{//loop with scheduled thread every 40ms
  if ((frameCounter & 4) == 4) {//fade all trails, very expensive
    var fx = 0
    var fy = 0
    while (fy < terminalSizeRows) {
      while (fx < terminalSizeColumns) {
        val charCurr = fadeGraphics.getCharacter(fx, fy)
        if (charCurr != null && charCurr.getCharacter != ' ' && charCurr.getForegroundColor != TextColor.ANSI.WHITE_BRIGHT) {
          val color    = charCurr.getForegroundColor
          val colorNew = TextColor.RGB(
            Math.max(0, color.getRed - fadeRate),
            Math.max(0, color.getGreen - fadeRate),
            Math.max(0, color.getBlue - fadeRate),
          )
          val charNew      = charCurr
            .withForegroundColor(colorNew)
          fadeGraphics.setCharacter(fx, fy, charNew)
        } else {
          fadeGraphics.setCharacter(fx, fy, ' ')
        }
        fx += 2
      }
      fx = 0
      fy += 1
    }
  }
  // ... add additional characters to the new frame
}

A variation of this algorithm is used in ScaLaMatrixRain.
Sorry for using while loops here. Scala lacks for loops.
Double buffering via Screen did not provide any performance benefit and resulted in adding flicker.
I understand Lanterna is not meant for high frame rate animation. But the effect is mostly working, just very CPU intensive.

You could keep the previous frame in memory instead of asking O(n*m) times for .getCharacter(fx, fy).
You could also calculate the next frame without any call to the library (specifically fadeGraphics.setCharacter) and only do that in the end of the calculation. This could save some time depending on the implementation of the library.
The code (with some refactorings) for the loop would be approximately:
/* This part will be parallelized. It has no side-effects */
val nextChars = previousFrame.map(line => {
    line.map(charCurr => {
        val condition = (charCurr != null && charCurr.getCharacter != ' ' && charCurr.getForegroundColor != TextColor.ANSI.WHITE_BRIGHT)
        if(condition){
            val color    = charCurr.getForegroundColor
            val colorNew = TextColor.RGB(
                Math.max(0, color.getRed - fadeRate),
                Math.max(0, color.getGreen - fadeRate),
                Math.max(0, color.getBlue - fadeRate),
            )
            charCurr.withForegroundColor(colorNew)
        } else {
            ' '
        }
    })
})

val completeRange = for
    i <- 0 until terminalSizeRows
    j <- 0 until terminalSizeColumns
    yield (i, j)

/* This part calls the library and will probably spend most of your CPU time */
completeRange.map((fx, fy) => {
    fadeGraphics.setCharacter(fx, fy, nextChars(fx)(fy))
})

If you provide a working example, I could assert the code runs. I only wrote it without compiling as given.
Also, as the code depends on an external library, I cannot infer the execution times and side-effects of each function. If you would provide links to the documentation, it would facilitate the answers.
